# Hologram: At the "crux" of the hologram, is there any potential for wave-wave interaction?

Tags: wavefunction, wave-particle-duality, hologram

Starting with Gabor's original 1948 paper:

https://www.nature.com/articles/Art56

And continuing where that paper left off with Gabor's Nobel Prize paper,

https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2018/06/gabor-lecture.pdf

My question amounts to the following:

---

Definition of Local Terms

**crux**: the point of intersection of the source beam and the reference beam

---

Is there any potential, under any conditions, for the wave-function of the reference beam to have a wave-wave interaction with the wave function of the source beam at the crux of the hologram?

In other words, does the hologram recorded have the potential to be merely a version of the "true hologram" because the energies of the reference beam and the source beams did not super-pose perfectly independently?

In other words, is there potential for inter-beam or inter-wave energy transmission?

Or is the super-position of the reference beam waves and the source beam waves **always perfect**, regardless of settings, angles, beam types, etc., *assuming the crux is perfectly located and everything is otherwise focused and correct*?

---

And I ask this with the following caveat: I understand that, in theory, "no" is probably the right answer.  But, in general, simple, mathematically useful theories are formulated by neglecting higher order effects that, in practice, may not be negligible.  For example, if one set out to go and build an information system out of hologram technologies, and the most efficient algorithms for data transmission turned out to deliver warped versions of the message sent, it would suddenly be clear that we neglected something in theory that impacted the **value or degree of difficulty of harnessing the value** of the theory in practice.

Comment: I'd suggest that you do a bunch of reading.  Find a copy of "OPTICAL HOLOGRAPHY" by Collier, Burkhardt & Lin, and digest every word.  Then research *nonlinear optics* and *four-wave mixing*.  That should give you the concepts, terminology, and many of the answers you need.

Comment: @S.McGrew Thanks man, will do

Comment: You should check in on the chat room you set up!

Comment: @S.McGrew Haha, yeah man -- definitely.  Manning the Xmas front